# Is there a way to make as many selenium web browsers appear as the user requests with a for loop or something. If so how can I do it?

Tags: python, selenium, loops, browser

I would like to make a for loop or loop of some sort in order to take an input and create that many selenium web browsers in python. How would I code this, because right now I have just hard-coded for about 10 browsers to open.

Comment: Why do you need to open multiple selenium browsers? Won't opening a new tab suffice?

Comment: No i need a new browser specifically for my project.